# CSS - center big div inside smaller one + hidden overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow, positioning

http://jsfiddle.net/vT65S/

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wide1">test</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="wide2">test</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="wide3">test</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container { width: 100%; text-align: center; margin: 20px 0; overflow: hidden; }
.container div { background: red; margin: 0 auto; }

.wide1 { width: 100px; }
.wide2 { width: 600px; } 
.wide3 { width: 1100px; }
```

I would like to have all "test" in one vertical line (centered). I need use it in situation where I don't know width of the inner divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! But with JavaScript ... http://jsfiddle.net/vT65S/10/

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(".container > *").each(function(){
       var m = ($(this).parent().innerWidth() - $(this).outerWidth())/2;
       $(this).css("margin-left", m);
    });
});
```

Maybe there is a solution with pure CSS (?)

Answer (score 2):

Centered to what? The outer container divs? You'll have to override the width of the inner divs, with something like `max-width: 100%`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vT65S/1/

```
.container div { background: red; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 100% }
```

Comment: but this changes the width of the inner div, what if there is sth else inside? eg. image - http://jsfiddle.net/vT65S/4/ or simply few paragraphs of text?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you actually want to happen - with that images example, what do you want the end result to look like? Also - you're explicitly setting the width of the images again, don't forget to `max-width` them: http://jsfiddle.net/vT65S/9/

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem - solved with CSS3 translateX

```
.container div{
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Cheers, best answer here. Works with relative parent and absolute child also